# Testing for color support in Linux shell scripts

Tags: shell, colors, terminal, termcap

This is the second time I've wanted to do this and again my google-fu has failed me.

When in the course of running a shell script (in my case a bash script) is there a program/script that tests whether the current shell supports color?

Alternatively is there a way to take the terminal type and easily determine if it supports color?

Either way it would be helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `tput colors`.

For my terminal with `TERM=xterm-256colors` the output is [drumroll] 256! Here are some other examples:

```
$ TERM=vt100 tput colors
-1
$ TERM=vt220 tput colors
-1
$ TERM=linux tput colors
8
$ TERM=cons25 tput colors
8
$ TERM=linux tput colors
8
$ TERM=rxvt-unicode tput colors
88
```

Alternatively `tput -Tvt100 colors` will also allow you to specify the terminal type you're interested in.

Comment: This! You sir are a gentleman and a scholar! This is such an easy and elegant solution, I'm not sure why it seems so obscure while searching.

Comment: I <3 StackOverflow... just when I need such ability, it's already answered :)